# How to submit Stripe Payment in a Formik Wizard, using React Elements?

Tags: reactjs, formik, formik-material-ui, stripe-payments

I'm creating a multi-step form in React using Formik and a stepper from Material-UI. That part is working (finally!) and I mostly understand how. Step 1 is a billing address, Step 2 is choosing a subscription plan, and Step 3 is payments using Stripe and their CardElements. This is where I fall off track.

I load Stripe high up in the app, so it's wrapped and available to my form. All good. I can successfully call Stripe methods when testing individually.

My Formik outer layer is here:

```
<Formik
    {...props}
    validationSchema={currentChild.props.validationSchema}
    onSubmit={async (values, helpers) => {
      if (isLastStep()) {
        await props.onSubmit(values, helpers);
        setCompleted(true);
      } else {
        setStep((s) => s + 1);
        helpers.setTouched({});
        if (step === 1) {
          await props.getCustomerId(values.billingEmail);
        }
      }
    }}
  >
  {... map over the steps, then the Back/Next/Submit buttons}
  </Formik>
```

At the formStepper creation, I call on `useStripe()` and `useElements()` and create a `CardElement` which gets passed into Step 3:

```
    const stripe = useStripe();
      const elements = useElements();
      let stripeCard = CardElement;
    
    <FormikStepper
                    initialValues={{ ...billingValues }}
                    onSubmit={(values, helpers) => {
                      createCustomer(values); //successfully sends formValues to be processed
                    }}
                    // I tried adding this here, but it isn't accessible inside the steps
// ETA: I put stripeProps inside the FormikStepper, which passes its properties down to the FormikStep inside. For non-Formik users, this works for the onBlur, onFocus, etc. as well as passing the initialValues.  Basically, I was hoping the card element could hitch a ride
                    stripeProps={{ card: stripeCard }}
                    getCustomerId={async (billingEmail) => {
                      await fetchCustomerId(billingEmail);
                    }}
                  >
                    <FormikStep
                      label="Billing Info"
                      validationSchema={object({ ...validationSchemaUsingYup })}
                    >
                      <Grid container item spacing={1}>
                        <CompanyProfile />
                      </Grid>
                    </FormikStep>
        
                    <FormikStep label="Choose Subscription">
                      <Grid container item spacing={1}>
                        <ChooseSubscription />
                      </Grid>
                    </FormikStep>
        
                    <FormikStep label="Review & Pay">
                      <Grid container item spacing={1}>
                        <StripePayment card={stripeCard} />
                      </Grid>
                    </FormikStep>
                  </FormikStepper>
```

Inside Step 3 I can render and use the CardElement as expected with this:

```
<props.card
    options={{
      style: {...styling}
    }}
  />
```

My confusion is in how to access this element in order to submit the data to Stripe?? How to I access the props that I passed into Step 3 and use that to process payment?
I tried putting the Stripe functions inside the function of Step 3, but they never got called, as the onSubmit functions are on the Parent of the step. I can't put the card number into the Formik initialValues without ruining the security aspect of using Stripe Elements. The closest I can get to anything is this error:

```
Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() IntegrationError: A valid Element name must be provided. Valid Elements are:
  card, cardNumber, cardExpiry, cardCvc, postalCode, paymentRequestButton, iban, idealBank, p24Bank, auBankAccount, fpxBank; you passed: object.
```

Updates in response to comments:
The stripeProps was a failed attempt to package info into `FormikStepper`, which passes props down to the children, `FormikStep`.
The `onSubmit` calls `createPaymentMethod`, below:

```
    async function createPaymentMethod(
    values,
    stripeData = stripeCard,
    customer = customerId
  ) {
    if (customer === undefined) {
      customer = fetchCustomerId(values.billingEmail);
    }

    return stripe
      .createPaymentMethod({
        type: "card",
        card: elements.getElement(stripeData), //no errors with CardElement, but not sure that's the SAME element from the form
      })
      .then((result) => {
        if (result.error) {
          console.log(result.error);
        } else {
          createSubscription({
            customer: customer,
            paymentMethodId: result.paymentMethod.id,
            items: [
              {
                price: values.TCPlan,
                quantity: values.TCPlanQuantity,
              },
            ],
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }

  // Step 2 of the Stripe process;
  // Called if createPaymentMethod is error-free
  function createSubscription({ customer, paymentMethodId, items }) {
    console.log(customer, paymentMethodId, items);
    let created = fetch(
      "https://xxxxxx.amazonaws.com/xxx/xxxx", // My API Gateway endpoint
      {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          customerId: customer,
          paymentMethodId: paymentMethodId,
          priceId: items,
        }),
      }
    );

    created
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.json());
      })
      // various error-handling offered by Stripe...
  }
```

Comment: I think there's missing some information here — where do you use `stripeProps` ? What is `<StripePayment>` and where's the code for it? "how to access this element in order to submit the data to Stripe?" — when the form is submitted your handler would get a reference to the Element and call a stripe.js function : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-stripe-official-q1loc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/components/demos/CardForm.js:782-822 / https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#useelements-hook I have never used Formik so I don't know how that works.

Comment: Might also help to share the code for `submitForm` that is throwing that Stripe IntegrationError.

Comment: @karllekko  - Thanks for responding! I made some updates, above.  The `<StripePayment />` is the last step, the one that displays the Stripe `cardElement`.  It's where you see `<props.card />` and includes a submit button that calls the Formik `onSubmit`.